# What determines the example tags? (tags in the placeholder of the tags section when asking new question)

Tags: support, tags

When asking a new question on any site, you see a placeholder in the tags section. This contains three tags, like this example from the [English Language and Usage site](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/ask):

> [image]

Or in words:

> at least one tag such as (adjectives prepositions british-english) max 5 tags

How are the tags that appear in the placeholder determined?

*Note: they do appear different at different times.*

Comment: What exactly is "creating a section"? Did you mean creating a question?

Comment: Those are called "example tags", will try digging some more about it

Comment: Pretty sure they're just three random tags. Either that, or the three most recently-used on that site.

Comment: @RobertLongson Yes. Sorry.

Comment: @ArtOfCode I looked at ELU three times, 10 minutes apart, and they were still the same.

Comment: @Peanut true, it's cached server side for several hours, probably 10-15 hours.

Answer (score 3):

After some research, I believe I figured this out.

On each site, there is a job/task running every 12 hours or so (might be bit different, e.g. 10 hours) which will do the following:

- Pick three tags in random from the top 30 tags or so (again, might be bit different, e.g. top 25 tags or 35 tags), top meaning having most questions.
- Cache those tags server side, and use them as the "example tags" when asking new question.
- There is probably a check in place to prevent same tag from being used twice in a row.

The top tags are easily accessible in the tags page (e.g. on [English Language and Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=popular)).

To verify this, I have used the [Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org), taking https://superuser.com/questions/ask as example and finding a date with two snapshots:

1. [March 11, 2016 06:22](https://web.archive.org/web/20160311062254/https://superuser.com/questions/ask)
2. [March 11, 2016 22:59](https://web.archive.org/web/20160311225923/https://superuser.com/questions/ask)

As you can see, different set of three tags each time.

Comment: Can you provide another sample?

Comment: Well, the English site isn't "big" enough to be archived more than once a day, and Stack Overflow requires to be logged in. Will try looking in other sites.

Comment: @Peanut didn't find, but pretty sure I'm correct. Until SE dev comes with a different answer, I'll leave this around